# is the memory complexity here is O(1) or O(N)?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, complexity-theory, time-complexity

The following method finds the longest contiguous sequence of integers in an unsorted array. (`{1,3,2,4,6,5}` will return `6`):

```
public static int what(int[] vec) {
    int m = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {
        int c  = 0;
        int n = i;

        do {
            n = find(vec, vec[n]+1);
            c++;
        } while (n != -1);

        if (c > m) {
            m = c;
        }
    }
    return m;
}

public static int find(int[] vec, int value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {
        if (vec[i] == value) {
            return i;
        }
     }
     return -1;
}
```

I see one variable outside the loop and two variables inside the loop, do the variables inside the loop make the memory complexity of this method be O(N)?

Also is the time complexity O(N^3)? (I'm talking about the worst-case).

I need to write this method with a better complexity function. Does anyone have any idea? (I can only use iterations, nothing fancier).

Comment: Is this a puzzle or what?

Comment: Posting an image for a code snippet is being as lazy as one could get.

Comment: @devnull You're right, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The function creates no new arrays, and it does not recurse.  It is therefore `O(1)` in memory.

The time complexity does appear to be `O(n^3)`, since (worst case) it uses a triply-nested scan over the supplied array.

It should be possible to make the search more optimal by noting that once you have called `find` you only need to consider the original list from the point at which `find` bailed out.

If the list was already sorted the algorithm requires just an `O(n)` linear scan.  Just start with `count = 1`, `max = vec[0]` and iterate from the second element.  If its in sequence, increment `count` and update your return value as applicable.  If the value is *not* in sequence, reset `count` to one again.  Repeat until done.

Since sorting can typically be done in `O(n log n)` and the second stage is `O(n)` the overall complexity would be substantially less than `O(n^3)`.  The sort algorithm itself is unlikely to retain the `O(1)` memory usage.

Comment: are you saying that if I sort the array it will be memory complexity of O(N)?

Comment: @SethKeno not necessarily, for example I believe an (in-place) quicksort is `O(log n)` in memory because of the state required for the recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

Its memory complexity is 0(1).  There is no storage that depends on n and no recursion.
Agree that time complexity O(n^3). Based on your algorithm, you would be better off taking the time to sort the array.

Comment: Thanks, and than what? even if the array is sorted, how can I run through the array once and find the sequence? let's say the array is {1,2,3,10,11,12,13,14,15}, it should return 6 as it's the biggest sequence.

Comment: @SethKeno where does the six come from?  Is it the _length_ of the longest (strictly monotonic) sequence?

Comment: @Alnitak yes. (15-10)+1, exactly what you said, the length of the longest sequence.

Comment: @SethKeno that's what I thought, but it didn't seem consistent with the example in the question.  It seems that what you're after is the longest sequence that _would appear if the list was sorted_ ?

Comment: If it was sorted, then its O(N) to find the longest continuous sequence. Just walk the entire vector starting from 1, if vec[i] == vec[i-1]+1, increment sequence_len, else max_len = max(sequence_len,max_len) and then sequence_len = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your method what return the longest sequence that can be found in the input vector. As instance,

{1,2,4,3} -> 4

{1,2,4,5} -> 2

The memory compexity of the methods is O(1) because there is no storage

The time compexity of the methods is O(n^3)

You can rewrite the methods as a sorting of the vector (for example with bubblesort (O(n^2))) and then you make the count with a linear scan (O(n)).

The complexity will be O(n^2)+O(n) ~> O(n^2) < O(n^3)

Comment: alright, how would I go N times on the array {1,2,3,4,5,20,21,22,23,99,100}, and return the right number (5)? If I have any variable to track the count of the sequence, it should reset if I find a different sequence.

Comment: @SethKeno the `O(n)` final stage is described in my answer.

Comment: I think I found a solution -> sort the array, than iterate once with 2 indexes one starting at the beginning of the array, and the 2nd starts at the end. advance both indexes one after the other, if one stops being a sequence, put the other value inside it, is should work I think right?

Comment: @Alnitak As you can't assume that the vector is sorted so you have to sort it yourself => You just said what i said ^^

Comment: @Kraiss the question as posed was ambiguous, as it wasn't clear that the OP wanted the _effective_ longest sequence (once sorted) rather than the sequence as ordered in the array.  I'd already written the `O(n)` solution to the latter problem.